# Adding more memory to h2o.ai Steam Prediction Service Builder

Tags: h2o

I trying to build a .war file in `h2o steam`'s prediction service builder using a (~800MB) `pojo` file (a similara pojo of size ~200MB also produced these same problems). However, when trying this, an error appears after clicking 'build':

```
Problem accessing /makewar. Reason:

    Compilation of pojo failed exit value 3  warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6


The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.BaseFileManager.makeByteBuffer(BaseFileManager.java:302)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.RegularFileObject.getCharContent(RegularFileObject.java:114)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.RegularFileObject.getCharContent(RegularFileObject.java:53)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.readSource(JavaCompiler.java:602)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:665)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:950)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:857)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:381)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:370)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:361)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:56)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:42)
```

I am launching the Prediction Service Builder from the command line following the instruction in [this](http://docs.h2o.ai/steam/latest-stable/prediction_service.html#build-and-run-the-builder-service) documentation. Is there a way to launch the service builder with more memory?

**UPDATE**
Using the command:
`$ GRADLE_OPTS=-Xmx4g ./gradlew jettyRunWar`

Trying to build a .war from the pojo returns the cli error:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/reedv/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.7-all/2glqtbnmvcq45bfjvhghri39p6/gradle-2.7/lib/gradle-core-2.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/reedv/Documents/h2o_production/h2o-steam/steam/prediction-service-builder/build/tmp/jettyRunWar/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
2017-09-21 15:22:48.084 -1000 [1222676357@qtp-1014435252-3] INFO MakeWarServlet - servletPath = /home/reedv/Documents/h2o_production/h2o-steam/steam/prediction-service-builder/build/tmp/jettyRunWar/webapp
2017-09-21 15:22:48.086 -1000 [1222676357@qtp-1014435252-3] INFO MakeWarServlet - tmpDir /tmp/makeWar316567921053262563022859149567148
2017-09-21 15:22:57.175 -1000 [1222676357@qtp-1014435252-3] INFO MakeWarServlet - added pojo model drf_denials_v4_v3-10-5-2.java
2017-09-21 15:22:57.190 -1000 [1222676357@qtp-1014435252-3] INFO MakeWarServlet - prejar null  preclass null
2017-09-21 15:22:58.047 -1000 [1222676357@qtp-1014435252-3] INFO Util - warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
2017-09-21 15:23:25.017 -1000 [1190941229@qtp-1014435252-0] INFO MakeWarServlet - tmpDir /tmp/makeWar432278342000106527922896081353600
2017-09-21 15:23:39.448 -1000 [1190941229@qtp-1014435252-0] INFO MakeWarServlet - added pojo model drf_denials_v4_v3-10-5-2.java
2017-09-21 15:23:39.569 -1000 [1190941229@qtp-1014435252-0] INFO MakeWarServlet - prejar null  preclass null
2017-09-21 15:23:40.651 -1000 [1190941229@qtp-1014435252-0] INFO Util - warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
2017-09-21 15:23:57.124 -1000 [1190941229@qtp-1014435252-0] INFO Util - OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000006efd00000, 1592786944, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
2017-09-21 15:23:57.604 -1000 [1190941229@qtp-1014435252-0] INFO Util - #
2017-09-21 15:23:57.605 -1000 [1190941229@qtp-1014435252-0] INFO Util - # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
2017-09-21 15:23:57.616 -1000 [1190941229@qtp-1014435252-0] INFO Util - # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 1592786944 bytes for committing reserved memory.
2017-09-21 15:23:57.619 -1000 [1190941229@qtp-1014435252-0] INFO Util - # An error report file with more information is saved as:
2017-09-21 15:23:57.622 -1000 [1190941229@qtp-1014435252-0] INFO Util - # /tmp/makeWar432278342000106527922896081353600/hs_err_pid32313.log
2017-09-21 15:23:57.747 -1000 [1190941229@qtp-1014435252-0] ERROR MakeWarServlet - doPost failed 
java.lang.Exception: Compilation of pojo failed exit value 1  warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000006efd00000, 1592786944, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 1592786944 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/makeWar432278342000106527922896081353600/hs_err_pid32313.log

    at ai.h2o.servicebuilder.Util.runCmd(Util.java:162)
    at ai.h2o.servicebuilder.MakeWarServlet.doPost(MakeWarServlet.java:151)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:943)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
2017-09-21 15:23:58.039 -1000 [1190941229@qtp-1014435252-0] ERROR MakeWarServlet - Compilation of pojo failed exit value 1  warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000006efd00000, 1592786944, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 1592786944 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/makeWar432278342000106527922896081353600/hs_err_pid32313.log
```

Increasing the memory allocation value to Xmx6g or Xmx7g still gives this same error.

Furthermore, looking for the file `/tmp/makeWar432278342000106527922896081353600/hs_err_pid32313.log` that was supposedly created by this error, there seems to not be a directory named "makeWar432278342000106527922896081353600" in my root tmp/ directory, so I'm not really sure where to look for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you started it with Gradle. In that case you can do `GRADLE_OPTS=-Xmx4g ./gradlew jettyrunwar` to start it with 4 GB of memory.

Comment: I started the service builder following the instructions here http://docs.h2o.ai/steam/latest-stable/prediction_service.html#build-and-run-the-builder-service, if that's what you mean (never used gradle before). Where do I add the `GRADLE_OPTS=-Xmx4g` command? Is is all a single line? (eg. `$ GRADLE_OPTS=Xmx4g ./gradlew jettyRunWar`)?

Comment: Yes all in a single line

Comment: Trying this did not produce any errors in the cli, but when trying to compile the pojo into a .war in the service builder, the the browser (chrome) gives the error screen "localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE." Nothing else seems to happen after this.

Comment: Nothing else seems to happen after this for a long time, then cil gives same `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the problem better. The service builder runs java internally to compile and build the services. It has an internal setting of 4 GB which is normally fine. In your case it looks like you need more. You can change that on this line https://github.com/h2oai/steam/blob/master/prediction-service-builder/src/main/java/ai/h2o/servicebuilder/Util.java#L42 Then just restart the prediction service builder with `./gradlew jettyrunwar`. I hope this helps.

Comment: Service builder produced that same error message as in the updadted questionn post. Also, trying to use the `steam` .war for the model with `java -Xmx6g -jar jetty-runner-9.3.9.M1.jar --port 55001 ~/Documents/h2o_production/h2o-steam/steam-1.1.6-linux-amd64/var/master/model/2/drf_denials_v4_2.war` also produces a `There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue` error. I think that maybe I just don't have enough memory to run model (which is wierd since it was successfully created in `h2o flow`). Accepting this answer for now for others who may have same problem.

Comment: Yes it looks like you need more than 6 GB -- try with more memory.